# How can i detect third party application has been finished in android?

Tags: android, process

I am developing the lock screen app.

If an user want to run the camera/call/other third party app in my lock screen app, can do it.

I want rerun my lock screen when these apps are finished. But I don't know when these apps are finished.

How can i detect third party application has been finished in android?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should start third party app using method:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_REQUEST);
```

You can get some guide in [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)